# Two image inputs in one form

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I have a form in which I collect user informations. Its pretty big and it should have two inputs for image uploading. So it should have two images uploading inside one form. I have a datebase where I store the image URL, and the first image input works perfectly, but I have no idea how can I now upload second image and store its url in the datebase.

**My form:**

```
<form action="forms/credit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" name="file" class="input-text required-entry" required="">

<input type="file" name="cofile" class="input-text required-entry" required="">

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

**My php image handler:**

```
$targetDir = "../images/";

$fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

$targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;

$fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){

    // Allow certain file formats

    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif','pdf');

    if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){

        // Upload file to server

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){

// Attempt insert query execution

$sql = "INSERT INTO credit (file, cofile) VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileName')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql) == false){
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    exit;
} 

}
    }
    }
```

So as I said, it works fine for the first image but it doesn't work fine for second. I guess I would need to use array or something like that, but can someone give me a hint or a code preview on how can I do it? I'm fairly new to PHP and I'm still learning a lot.

Thanks!

Comment: That's because you never used the $_FILES array for it.

Comment: Thanks! Can you help me with it? I saw some tutorails that it can be done using array but as I sad I'm new and everything I try ends up in error and me not understanding the code at all.

Comment: Why _would_ it work with the second, when your code contains _nothing_ whatsoever that actually handles that second image?

Comment: @04fs can you explain me how can I handle the second image aswell? I said I'm new and that I'm still learning

Comment: `name="file"` is what made `$_FILES["file"]` come into existence. Can you guess now, what you should access to process the result of `name="cofile"` accordingly …?

Comment: A lot things came to my mind @04FS, for example, I thought I can create second variable named "$fileName2" which will have $_FILES["cofile"], but then how can I use it inside my code? can I add || $_FILES["cofile"] or OR $_FILES["cofile"] to every function so it can handle the second file aswell

Comment: Your script logic makes little sense in that regard to begin with - you (try to) access `$_FILES["file"]` already with `$fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);`, and then only _later_ you check `!empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])` … Start by putting things in an order that actually makes sense. And then, decide whether you want to make it mandatory to upload two files - then you should check for the presence of both at the same time. If not, you can check each on its own.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the file the same way you store `$_FILES["file"]`. This can be accessed using `$_FILES["cofile"]`

Something along the lines of this should help (untested)

```
$fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

$targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;

$cofileName = basename($_FILES["cofile"]["name"]);

$targetcoFilePath = $targetDir . $cofileName;

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath) &&  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["cofile"]["tmp_name"], $targetcoFilePath))
```